# How to properly implement PHPWord to CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, phpword

I am trying to generate a word document using `phpword` through `cakephp` but I always get a fatal error:

```
Error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor' not found
File:C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis\app\Controller\MainController.php
Line: 1016
```

line 1016:

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('resources/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx');
```

I placed the phpword files in this path:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis\app\Vendor
```

And the docx file here:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis\app\Vendor\PhpWord\resources
```

Is there anything wrong on how I implemented `phpword` with `cakephp`?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you added the plugin as a dependency in the controller using `App::uses`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install PHPWord through Composer as CakePHP is using Composer to manage its dependancies.

Comment: I get this problem when installing composer:

_The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond._

Comment: Tried both installation for windows and Command-line, same results.

Comment: That is the windows installation I was referring to.